# I can get Google Geocode API to work, but not the Google Place API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

Here's my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true";
    var API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=chicken+greenvile+sc&sensor=true";

$.getJSON(API, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

If I comment out the second var API, I get a returned result in the console log, no problems. If I uncomment the second one, I get the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." .. so if I add "callback=?" to the end of the second var API, I then get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "... Which is the JSON being returned, but not in the right format?.. I don't know. What am I doing wrong? I just want to be able to use the Places API like the Geocode API. Geocode works perfectly...

Comment: try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamn/vs8p5/19/)

Comment: @shyamnathan that link doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Was this on the wrong post?

Comment: sorry posted answer on wrong question page will delete it

Comment: Maybe you've gone over your API limit? ["Both the Google Nearby Search and the Google Places Text Search services share the same usage limits. However, the Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota. If you've purchased the Google Places API as part of your Maps API for Business contract, the multiplier may be different. Please refer to the Google Maps API for Business documentation for details."](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

Comment: I just started trying this stuff out yesterday. I've only used like 100 requests so far. It's really weird. Another thing is, I don't even have a key speicified in the two API links above. But the top one still works. Generally I should be using something like this:
    maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=chicken+greenvile+sc&sensor=true&key=(mykeyhere)

Comment: That is not the way you are supposed to use the API. Why would you use getJSON with the API as the URL? You can't do AJAX request cross domains anyway.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) (for the web service), or [for the Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), at a minimum the Places API _requires_ a key.

Comment: You can use an ajax request cross domain?... read my code, I do it with the second API variable commented out. Also I get the same results with or without a key, so what difference does it make? I mean test the code out for yourselves guys, it works..

Answer (score 0):

The Places API is called when the Maps API is called.  It is one of the libraries similar to weather, drawing or geometry.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(YOUR KEY)&sensor=false&libraries=*places*
```

One the library is added the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Autocomplete) can be used in your app

Comment: I get the same results with or without the key.

Comment: Can you post your entire code?  What type of server are you using?